# Auto delete item from minicart in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, ajax, mini-cart, delete, cart-items

I have 2 items in cart suppose A & B.
When customer delete item A from **minicart** then auto delete item B.

How the ajax will call 2 times, I have done this in controller's execute function (delete both item together when delete first item) but it is not working for me.
[image]

Here is the code snippet:
I have **override** this file  **Magento/Checkout/Controller/Sidebar/RemoveItem.php**
So my file is **app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Sidebar/RemoveItem.php**

```
 public function execute()
{
    if (!$this->getFormKeyValidator()->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/cart/');
    }
    $itemId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id'); 
      

    //get all cart items
    $data = $this->resultCart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    $valid = 1;
    foreach ($data as $item) {
       $sku = $item->getSku();
        if($sku == 'additional_item') //item B
        {
            $item_id = $item->getItemId();
        }
    }


    if(isset($item_id)){
        if($itemId == $item_id){
            $valid = 0;
        }
    }
    try {
        if($valid == 0){
             return $this->jsonResponse('We can\'t remove Sanitize item.');
        }
        if($valid){
             
            $this->sidebar->checkQuoteItem($itemId); 
            $this->sidebar->removeQuoteItem($itemId); //Removing item A

            if(isset($item_id)){ //removing the item B from here
                 $this->sidebar->checkQuoteItem($item_id);
                 $this->sidebar->removeQuoteItem($item_id);
             }

            return $this->jsonResponse();
        }

    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
    } catch (\Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->critical($e);
        return $this->jsonResponse(__('An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->critical($e);
        return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you dont post any code?!

Comment: @Black, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

In this segment:

```
 if(isset($item_id)){ //removing the item B from here
     $this->sidebar->checkQuoteItem($item_id);
     $this->sidebar->removeQuoteItem($item_id);
 }
```

Do you have something in place that changes `$item_id` to the "B" product you are trying to remove? I understand you may have just changed it out for clarity in the post, but wanted to make sure... As it is, you just removed `$item_id`, so it's `unset` (and will just get passed over) unless you update `$item_id` to be the "B" product.